# removeDialog(int id) closed when user touches screen outside this window

Tags: android

I am using removeDialog(int id) in my android application after using showDialog(int id). It is working fine functionality wise. Problem is that when user touches the screen outside the Dialog window, the window is closed. It should not happen. How can i prevent this dialog window from closing when user touches outside the dialog window? I am posting code snippet where i am using showDialog(1). I haven't created or defined any Dialog.

```
    private void getLocationData() {

        showDialog(1);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(WaveServices.isNetworkAvailable(LoginActivity.this)){
                    locationArrayList = WaveServices.getLocation();
                    WavePreferences.setLocationInfo(locationArrayList);
                }else{
                    locationArrayList= WavePreferences.getLocationInfo();
                }

.
.
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: try setCancelable(false) on your dialog

Comment: setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);  in your activity

Comment: First of all, Thanks for replying "Software Sainath" and "raj". It might be a silly question but Where should i write these statements?

Answer (score 1):

You can set cancelable option like below:

```
    your_dialog.setCancelable(false);
    your_dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Comment: First of all, Thanks for replying "Manish Patel". It might be a silly question but Where should i write these statements? I am just usiong showDialog(1) without creating any.

Comment: at the place where you just created your dialog. it's easy.

Answer (score 0):

```
myDialog.setCancelable(false);
```

should help you.
Hope it helps.

Comment: First of all, Thanks for replying "Anamika". It might be a silly question but Where should i write this statement? I am just using showDialog(1) without creating any.

Comment: When you create the dialog.